# Postgresql from Json Object to array

Tags: json, postgresql

How can I convert a Postgresql stored json of this form

```
{"Kategorie": [{"ID": "environment", "ID": "economy"}]}
```

to get ["environment", "economy"] only using Postgresqls json flavoured syntax. The array in the stored source has here two elements, but may contain more (or only one). And the resulting array should result in all value elements.

Comment: Have you tried any approaches to this type of conversion?

Comment: Frankly no, as I do not know if it's even possible.

Comment: That isn't valid JSON. You can't have an object with the same key. Did you mean `{"Kategorie": [{"ID": "environment"}, {"ID": "economy"}]}`?

Comment: @dommage Yes, I tried to make a MWE without verification

Comment: Try this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/117094/40955

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may give you something to work with:

```
SELECT ARRAY(select json_extract_path_text(x, 'ID') from
    json_array_elements(
        '{"Kategorie": [{"ID": "environment"}, {"ID": "economy"}]}'::json->'Kategorie') 
    as x)
```

The result is a text array:

`{environment,economy}`

It is entirely possible that there's a cleaner way to do this :)

The [JSON operators documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html) has the details. (This is 9.3+ only, 9.2 had very few utility functions.)

Comment: This works select json_extract_path(json_array_elements(category#>'{Kategorie}'), 'ID') from dataset but will give me multiple rows for each source row. As you suggested, Array() should do this, but when I wrap it into select array(....) I receive the error syntax error at or near "json_extract_path". That's really strange

Comment: Ok, this finally does what I want: select to_json(array(select json_extract_path(json_array_elements(category#>'{Kategorie}'), 'ID'))) from dataset